# Removing then adding an element via an angular directive breaks ng-model on input[radio]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a custom directive to toggle elements from the DOM. It's similar to ng-show, but with actual dom manipulation instead of hiding via styles. For reasons outside the scope of this question, I can't use ng-show.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('daKeep', [
        function () {
      function link($scope, element, attributes) {

            var cacheElement, insertionElement;

            // the TRUTHY expression to watch
            var expression = attributes.daKeep;

            function removeElement() {
              if (insertionElement === undefined) {
                insertionElement = element.prev();
                cacheElement = element;
                element.remove();
              }
            }

            function addElement() {
              if (insertionElement !== undefined) {
                insertionElement.after(cacheElement);
                insertionElement = undefined;
              }
            }

            if (!$scope.$eval(expression)) {
              removeElement();
            }

            // watch the expression in $scope context to see when it changes
            $scope.$watch(expression, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            // Ignore first-run values since we've
            // already defaulted the element state
            if (newValue === oldValue) {
              return;
            }

            // Show element
            if (newValue) {
              addElement();
            } else {
              removeElement();
            }
          });
        }

      // Return the directive configuration.
      return ({
        link: link,
        restrict: "A"
      });
        }
    ]);
```

It was working fine for my needs, but when I used it on a container element that housed some input[radio] buttons, the bindings for my radio buttons broke when the element was added back.

Is there a way to fix my directive so the bindings won't break?

Example here: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKmYnBXxDBzaRrXWbR2k?p=preview)

Comment: If you dont want to use ng-show because you dont want the elements to remain in the markup, you can try ng-if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead of the custom directive? It does the same thing as `ng-show` but instead of applying styles it removes or recreates the DOM.

```
  <div ng-if="keepRadioButtons">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="true" ng-model="selectedValue" />Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-value="false" ng-model="selectedValue" />No
  </div>
```

Comment: Using ng-if didn't directly fix the binding problem, but you're right in that it accomplishes the same goal. The ng-if docs explain it: "An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope." The binding solution was to wrap selectedValue in an object off the scope. Bind ng-model to foo.selectedValue instead of selectedValue directly.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem is the fact that you call `element.remove()` which removes data angular attaches to jQuery or jQLite collections for its bindings.

`ng-if` is an alternative, but to strictly fix your issue, call `detach` instead of `remove`.